# ¿A qué se debe este error: "Notice: Uninitialized string offset"?Tratando de iterar los valores de un array

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```html
<form method="POST" action="Capt_Calif.php">
<?php
    //listado de los alumnos del grupo que estan en esa materia:
     foreach ($alumbosByGpoMater as $alumno): 
?>
    <tr>    
        <!-- imprime contador de registros, o numero de registros que aparecen recuperados  -->
        <td><?php if ($i <= $num_rows) {  echo $i; } ?></td>
        <!-- imprime matrticula de alumno  -->
        <td><?php echo $alumno[0];?></td>
        <!-- imprime nombre de alumno  -->
        <td><?php echo $alumno[1];?></td>
        <!-- casillas para capturar caliicaciones  e inasistencias por periodo  -->
        <!-- parcialP1= calificacion periodo e inasistencias del periodo 1  -->
        <!-- intentaba enviar un solo arreglo con ambas columnas: calificacion e inasistencias por periodo  -->
        <td><input type="text" name="parcialP1[]" class="p1" size="3"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="parcialP1[]" class="ip1" size="3"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="parcialP2[]" class="p2" size="3"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="parcialP2[]" class="ip2" size="3"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="parcialP3[]" class="p3" size="3"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="parcialP3[]" class="ip3" size="3"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="final[]" class="final" size="3"></td>
        <!-- parametros enviados para ser usados en la clausula where,   -->
        <td><input type="hidden" name="idgpo" value="<?php echo $alumno[7]; ?>"></td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="idalumno" value="<?php echo $alumno[10]; ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
        $i++;  //incrementamos contador en 1 luego de cada alumno recuperado, 
    endforeach
    ?>   
    </tbody>
    </table>    
    <button type="submit" name="formAlumno" class="btn btn-success">Guardar</button>
</div>
</form>
```

```php
<?php

require '../../Model/Model_Docentes.php';

$connect = conectar(); //conexion a la bd

if ( isset($_POST['formAlumno']) && !empty($_POST['idgpo']) && !empty($_POST['idalumno']) ) {
    //var_dump($_POST['idgpo']);
    //var_dump($_POST['idalumno']);
    var_dump($_POST['parcialP1']);

    //recibiendo los parametros de grupo y alumno a quienes pertenece cada calificacion y numero de inasistencias
    $grupo      = $_POST['idgpo']; 
    $alumno     = $_POST['idalumno'];

    //recibiendo el arreglo que contiene los valores de las columnas de calificacion e inasistencias del primer periodo
    $parcialP1  = $_POST['parcialP1']; 

    if(is_array($parcialP1))
    {
        $values = array();

        foreach($parcialP1 as $fila => $valor)
        {
            //intentando recibir la calificacion del periodo1
            $p1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $valor[0]); 
            //intentando recibir num de inasitencias del periodo1
            $inasisP1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $valor[1]);
            $values[] = "('$p1', '$inasisP1')";
        }
        $sql = "UPDATE alumno_grupo SET parcial1 = '".$p1."', inasisP1 = '".$inasisP1."' WHERE idAlumno = $grupo AND idGrupo = $alumno";
        $sql .= implode(', ', $values);
        mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
    } //if is array

    //   }

}  //isset

?>
```

```
//haciendo var_dump al ingresar una calificacion y una inasistencia:
array(74) { [0]=> string(1) "9" [1]=> string(1) "0" [2]=> string(0) "" [3]=> string(0) "" [4]=> string(0) "" [5]=> string(0) "" [6]=> string(0) "" [7]=> string(0) "" [8]=> string(0) "" [9]=> string(0) "" [10]=> string(0) "" [11]=> string(0) "" [12]=> string(0) "" [13]=> string(0) "" [14]=> string(0) "" [15]=> string(0) "" [16]=> string(0) "" [17]=> string(0) "" [18]=> string(0) "" [19]=> string(0) "" [20]=> string(0) "" [21]=> string(0) "" [22]=> string(0) "" [23]=> string(0) "" [24]=> string(0) "" [25]=> string(0) "" [26]=> string(0) "" [27]=> string(0) "" [28]=> string(0) "" [29]=> string(0) "" [30]=> string(0) "" [31]=> string(0) "" [32]=> string(0) "" [33]=> string(0) "" [34]=> string(0) "" [35]=> string(0) "" [36]=> string(0) "" [37]=> string(0) "" [38]=> string(0) "" [39]=> string(0) "" [40]=> string(0) "" [41]=> string(0) "" [42]=> string(0) "" [43]=> string(0) "" [44]=> string(0) "" [45]=> string(0) "" [46]=> string(0) "" [47]=> string(0) "" [48]=> string(0) "" [49]=> string(0) "" [50]=> string(0) "" [51]=> string(0) "" [52]=> string(0) "" [53]=> string(0) "" [54]=> string(0) "" [55]=> string(0) "" [56]=> string(0) "" [57]=> string(0) "" [58]=> string(0) "" [59]=> string(0) "" [60]=> string(0) "" [61]=> string(0) "" [62]=> string(0) "" [63]=> string(0) "" [64]=> string(0) "" [65]=> string(0) "" [66]=> string(0) "" [67]=> string(0) "" [68]=> string(0) "" [69]=> string(0) "" [70]=> string(0) "" [71]=> string(0) "" [72]=> string(0) "" [73]=> string(0) "" } 

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\cebProcedular\View\Docente\Capt_Calif.php on line 28

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\cebProcedular\View\Docente\Capt_Calif.php on line 28

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\cebProcedular\View\Docente\Capt_Calif.php on line 27

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\cebProcedular\View\Docente\Capt_Calif.php on line 28

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\cebProcedular\View\Docente\Capt_Calif.php on line 27
```

Comment: El error está en querer llamar a `$valor[0]`. ¿Qué valores te interesan del array `$parcialP1`?

Comment: todos, pensaba poner en uno solo las calificaciones y las inasistencias.

Comment: para el ejemplo que puse, es como si nadamas recogiera la calificación del primer parcial y las inasistencias, del primer alumno que aparece.
La idea era que se recogieran en arreglos separados calificacion e inasistencias por parcial: 1,2,3,final. de cada alumno que aparece listado. Y con un update poner esos datos recogidos en el registro que le corresponde al idGrupo e idAlumno de la tabla

Comment: Pregunto porque tenés definidos 74 inputs que se envían dentro del mismo array. ¿Cómo están organizados los datos? El primer input es la nota, el segundo las inasistencias... ¿y los otros 72 inputs?

Comment: para este grupo que toma esa materia son 37 alumnos en total, y son 37 inputs de la columna calificación y otros 37 de la columna inasistencias, por eso aparecen 74 en el var_dump.Y esto es solo tomando calificación e inasistencias del parcial1,
Pero el número de alumnos varia en cada grupo que se seleccione, se desplega una cantidad diferente de alumnos e inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en esta parte del código:

```php
foreach($parcialP1 as $fila => $valor) {
```

donde el `foreach` está recorriendo el array `$parcialP1`, asignando cada valor a `$valor`. Dentro del bucle, `$valor` ya es un ítem del array. Por lo tanto `$valor[0]` es el primer caracter del item, y `$valor[1]` es el segundo caracter.

Cuando un item del array no tiene al menos dos caracteres, se dispara el error.

---

Creo que sería más sencillo separar notas e inasistencias en 2 arrays distintos. Sin embargo, podemos resolverlo así como está.

Asumiendo que se reciben los valores dentro del array `parcialP1[]`, listados de la siguiente forma:

```php
$parcialP1[0]; //nota del primer alumno
$parcialP1[1]; //inasistencias del primer alumno
$parcialP1[2]; //nota del segundo alumno
$parcialP1[3]; //inasistencias del segundo alumno
//etc.
```

Para poder recorrer las notas e inasistencias de cada alumno, utilizamos el siguiente bucle:

```php
$n = count($parcialP1);
$num_alumno = 1;

//bucle que avanza 2 items por cada iteración
for ($i = 1; $i < $n; $i += 2, ++$num_alumno) {
    $p1 = $parcialP1[$i - 1];
    $inasisP1 = $parcialP1[$i];
    echo "Alumno: $num_alumno \t Nota: $p1.\t Inasistencias: $inasisP1 \n";
}
```

Ejemplo de resultado:

```
Alumno: 1    Nota: 9.    Inasistencias: 15 
Alumno: 2    Nota: 4.    Inasistencias: 0 
Alumno: 3    Nota: 10.   Inasistencias: 11
```

Este código probablemente se podría implementar de otra manera, pero lo estoy haciendo así para que sea más sencillo de entender.

<kbd>[Ejemplo en rextester.com](http://rextester.com/RETCD65444)</kbd>

Comment: si tiene toda la razón así debería ser, el update puede ir después dentro del bucle?

Comment: Claro. En el ejemplo, sólo lo estoy imprimiendo para mostrar cómo sería, pero se puede realizar el UPDATE en el bucle. De todas formas, primero probaría tener todos los valores correctos. En especial, el id de alumno, que no me queda claro cómo lo estás obteniendo y no sé si está bien. La respuesta apuntaba a explicar el bucle donde tenías el error, pero creo que todavía hay que seguir depurando. Cualquier cosa, podés volver a hacer otra pregunta con el código actualizado.

Comment: de acuerdo, el idAlumno e idGrupo son llaves foraneas de la tabla alumno_grupo que es donde ingreso las calificaciones e inasistencias, por eso las ingreso con un update porque busca donde este el alumno y grupo.

Comment: Sí, eso está claro. Pero si el ID de alumno lo estás recibiendo del formulario, creo que habría que ver si es el correcto para cada iteración del bucle. Simplemente imprimiendo algo como `echo "alumno $alumno grupo $grupo nota $p1"` alcanzaría para ver si está bien

Comment: si, viene del formulario, solo que esta hidden,

Comment: Una vez que tengas el código, hacé la prueba: `echo "UPDATE alumno $alumno grupo $grupo nota $p1"` ... Si están bien los valores, lo llevás a la base de datos.

Comment: de acuerdo muchas, gracias por toda la ayuda, saludos, 
muchas gracias

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47849/discussion-between-armando-arellano-and-mariano).

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo una solución más simple.

Primero tienes que cambiar en tu HTML en el atributo `name` de los `inputs` de esta manera:

```
<input type="text" name="parcial[<?php echo $i-1; ?>][]" class="p1" size="3">
<input type="text" name="parcial[<?php echo $i-1; ?>][]" class="ip1" size="3">
<input type="text" name="parcial[<?php echo $i-1; ?>][]" class="p2" size="3">
<input type="text" name="parcial[<?php echo $i-1; ?>][]" class="ip2" size="3">
<input type="text" name="parcial[<?php echo $i-1; ?>][]" class="p3" size="3">
<input type="text" name="parcial[<?php echo $i-1; ?>][]" class="ip3" size="3">
```

La variable `$i` lo haz iniciado con `1` por eso lo estoy restando para que empiece el index del array de `0`;

Y aquí pasas los valores de cada alumno en un `foreach`:

```
if (isset($_POST['formAlumno']) && !empty($_POST['idgpo']) && !empty($_POST['idalumno'])) {        

    $grupo   = $_POST['idgpo'];
    $alumno  = $_POST['idalumno'];        
    $parcial = $_POST['parcial'];

    if (is_array($parcial)) {

        foreach ($parcial as $value) {

            $p1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $value[0]); // campo 1
            $inasisP1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $value[1]); ; // campo 2

            $sql = " UPDATE alumno_grupo SET parcial1 = '".$p1."', inasisP1 = '".$inasisP1."' WHERE idAlumno = $grupo AND idGrupo = $alumno ";
            mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: lo probaré muchas gracias, saludos